CkEditor can't upgraded correctly
In a symfony 6 project that used nodejs in the integrated webpack seeing this model error inside my Ckeditor, I tried to upgrade the ckeditor.

The Ckeditor is upgraded successfuly

Thanks in advance.
after running the command npm run build
still seeing the same model error

Hi, is symfony cache cleared ?

Yeah cache cleared from symfony and from node and I opened a new incognito tab in the browser

Did you use php bin/console assets:install after the upgrade ?

Yes I did it but still doesn't work
